# what if the filter window size is an even number in Gaussian filtering?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, filtering, gaussian

I know usually people prefer to choose the odd number as the size of Gaussian Filtering, and since the image made of discrete pixels, we can always locate the central pixel.

But what if the size is an even number? There will lead to several questions:

1. how will the Gaussian filter be, should it be symmetric or asymmetric?
2. what if the size number equals to 2?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There really is no such choice to be made.

A Gaussian filtering kernel that is shifted will result in a smoothing + a shift of the image. If you want a filter that doesn’t shift the image, the filter must have the origin of the Gaussian at the origin of the kernel, typically the central pixel of an odd-sized kernel.

Once we have established that, using an even-sized filter must lead to an asymetrical kernel. It is not really desirable to have an asymmetrical smoothing filter (unless we’re talking about adaptive filtering) because the asymmetry introduces a bias.

So, we’re stuck with an odd-sized filter. An even-sized filter will introduce either a bias or a shift of half a pixel.

A 2-pixel kernel cannot be a Gaussian filter because it takes at least 5 samples to represent a Gaussian kernel with sufficient detail for it to present the positive aspects of the Gaussian filter. With fewer samples, the filter will not behave like a Gaussian filter.

For more information about Gaussian filtering, I recommend that you read [this blog post](https://www.crisluengo.net/index.php/archives/22) that I wrote 10 years ago.