# How does correlation work for an even-sized filter in this example?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

(I know a question like this exists, but I wanted help with a specific example)

If the linear filter has even dimensions, how is the "center" defined? i.e. in the following scenario:

```
filter = np.array([[a, b],
                   [c, d]])
```

and the image was:

```
image = np.array([[0, 1, 0],
                  [1, 1, 1],
                  [0, 1, 0]])
```

what would be the result of correlation of the image with the linear filter?

Answer (score 0):

Which of the elements of the even-sized filter is considered the origin is an arbitrary choice. Each implementation will make a different choice. Though `a` and `d` are the two most likely choices for reasons of similarity of the two image dimensions.

For example, MATLAB's `imfilter` (which implements correlation, not convolution) does the following:

```matlab
f = [1,2;4,8];
img = [0,1,0;1,1,1;0,1,0];
imfilter(img,f,'same')

ans =

    14    13     4
    11     7     1
     2     1     0
```

meaning that `a` is the origin of the kernel in this case. Other implementations might make a different choice.

Comment: Note related answers: [Why should the size of the kernel be odd?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53494632/7328782), and [what if the filter window size is an even number in Gaussian filtering?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52349082/7328782).